# Indicate no time limit

Tags: lists, time, symbols

I am displaying a To Do list that has time limits involved. However an item doesn't have to have a due date/time.

Users are finding my current UI confusing, as they believe a blank time limit, means "the same as above", as if they are grouped. For example:

[image: To Do example]

Task 4 doesn't have a time limit. But users believe that it is grouped with Task 3, and has a time limit of 1 week.

I believe I need to put something in the "time" column for task 4, but I'm not sure how best to indicate this. I've thought of writing "none" or putting an "infinity" symbol, but neither of these feel right.

Comment: Outlook use "none", so it is kind of stantard. But on the top of the column put the label "Due Date"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is clear all the way down the column that it refers to a due date or time limit, you can just put "None" for those that don't have this.

Answer (score 0):

I feel a better way to represent the list would be to have a time badge against the tasks as shown below instead of having it before the task name.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Open** (as in "open ended") might work. Would probably fit whether the timed tasks were labelled **1 Day**, **1 Week** or with explicit dates.

Comment: This could be confused with the action “open” where the user might expect to see more details on the task.